# ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception when adding a document to Lucene Index (v 5.1.0)

Tags: lucene

I keep getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception after adding a couple of documents to the index. I have a thread that adds the documents to indexes across multiple machines. 
I'm not sure if this has something to do with how I add fields to the Document. The "text" could be of any length.

```
public static void CreateIndex(){
    int count = 0;
    try {
        IndexWriters.initIndexWriters(); //these are located on different machines on the network

        int whichIndex = 0;

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(Constants.MY_XML);
        BufferedReader t = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis, "UTF-8"));

        String title = "";
        String articleId = "";
        String str;

        while ((str = t.readLine()) != null)
        {
                title = str.replace("<title>", "").replace("</title>", "").trim();
                str = t.readLine();
                articleId = str.replace("<id>", "").replace("</id>", "").trim();
                str = t.readLine();
                text = str.replace("<text>", "").replace("</text>", "").trim();

                Document lDoc = new Document();

                Field id = new TextField("id", articleId, Field.Store.YES);
                Field title = new TextField("title", title, Field.Store.YES);
                Field text = new TextField("text", text.toString(), Field.Store.YES);
                Doc.add(id);
                Doc.add(title);
                Doc.add(text);

                IndexWriters.indW[whichIndex].addDocument(Doc);  //exception thrown here after adding couple of documents

                whichIndex = (whichIndex+1)%(Constants.NUMNODES*Constants.PER_NODE_INDEXES_COUNT);
                ++count;
                }
                articleId = "";
                text = null;
                title = "";
            }
            }
        }
        IndexWriters.closeWriters();

    }catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch( Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And the stack trace is as below

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 32768
at org.apache.lucene.util.StringHelper.murmurhash3_x86_32(StringHelper.java:188)
at org.apache.lucene.util.BytesRefHash.doHash(BytesRefHash.java:460)
at org.apache.lucene.util.BytesRefHash.rehash(BytesRefHash.java:432)
at org.apache.lucene.util.BytesRefHash.add(BytesRefHash.java:323)
at org.apache.lucene.index.TermsHashPerField.add(TermsHashPerField.java:154)
at org.apache.lucene.index.DefaultIndexingChain$PerField.invert(DefaultIndexingChain.java:657)
at org.apache.lucene.index.DefaultIndexingChain.processField(DefaultIndexingChain.java:344)
at org.apache.lucene.index.DefaultIndexingChain.processDocument(DefaultIndexingChain.java:300)
at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriterPerThread.updateDocument(DocumentsWriterPerThread.java:232)
at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.updateDocument(DocumentsWriter.java:458)
at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.updateDocument(IndexWriter.java:1350)
at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.addDocument(IndexWriter.java:1138)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the assumption being made in your code is that:

`Constants.NUMNODES*Constants.PER_NODE_INDEXES_COUNT` is equal to (or less than) `IndexWriters.indW.length`

It would appear that assumption is incorrect.

(These are also a bunch of extraneous `}`s in there, but if it compiles, I'll assume that's just something that got left behind when you edited for posting here)

Comment: Actually Constants.NUMNODES*Constants.PER_NODE_INDEXES_COUNT is equal to IndexWriters.indW.length.